# Set File Type on Directory Upload to Google Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

When I upload a set of files to a bucket on Google Storage, they are automatically assigned file types ("text/html", "application/json", etc.).  But when I do a directory upload via the developer console, the files in the directory all get type "application/octet-stream".  How do I get Google Storage to automatically assign file types to the contents of an uploaded directory?

Comment: How do you do the upload? Via the developer Console? Via gsutil? programmatically (which language)?

Comment: @LundinCast This is with the developer console.  The question has been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a bug in the developer console.  This problem comes from adding a directory via drag-and-drop.  Uploading a directory via the "Upload Folder" button fixes this problem (it associates the correct file types with the files in the directory).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in your response above,

> This is likely a bug in the developer console. This problem comes from adding a directory via drag-and-drop. Uploading a directory via the "Upload Folder" button fixes this problem (it associates the correct file types with the files in the directory).
>   this does seem a bug

This does seem to be a bug. **All Google Cloud Platform bugs should be reported on the public issue tracker.** You might want to file a bug at [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187243&template=1162869) so that this can be further investigated.